# what should i do to fix this upstream dependency issue with sveltekit and netify-cms

Tags: npm, svelte, netlify-cms

I have installed sveltekit and deployed the sveltekit template to netify.

I want to link it to netify-cms and then do some actually website building but it caused this error when trying to download the npm package.

```
C:\Users\pjsup\code\ponders-showcase>npm i netlify-cms-app
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from netlify-cms-app@2.15.40
npm ERR!   node_modules/netlify-cms-app
npm ERR!     netlify-cms-app@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from netlify-cms-app@2.15.40
npm ERR!     node_modules/netlify-cms-app
npm ERR!       netlify-cms-app@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.0" from netlify-cms-core@2.48.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/netlify-cms-core
npm ERR!       netlify-cms-core@"^2.48.0" from netlify-cms-app@2.15.40
npm ERR!       node_modules/netlify-cms-app
npm ERR!         netlify-cms-app@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     7 more (netlify-cms-widget-date, ...)
npm ERR!   39 more (@emotion/core, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0-0" from react-split-pane@0.1.92
npm ERR! node_modules/netlify-cms-core/node_modules/react-split-pane
npm ERR!   react-split-pane@"^0.1.85" from netlify-cms-core@2.48.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/netlify-cms-core
npm ERR!     netlify-cms-core@"^2.48.0" from netlify-cms-app@2.15.40
npm ERR!     node_modules/netlify-cms-app
npm ERR!       netlify-cms-app@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\pjsup\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pjsup\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-06T12_26_54_989Z-debug.log
```

Is this because the netify-cms cannot work with sveltekit yet? It claims to work with Sapper its predecessor.
https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/add-to-your-site/